# Turn off double-click undock in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, multiple-monitors

I keep accidentally double-clicking my tabs in VS2010 and undocking them.  Is it possible to turn off this behavior?

Note: I'm using Document Well 2010 Plus from the Productivity Power Tools, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: A good question! Personally I like (in other more configurable applications) to "double click" to close an active tab, and "double click" on the 'empty section' of the tab-bar to open a new, un-named document .. 

Any hints from anyone?

Comment: How can i add this feature as a wish list to MS?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589302/how-to-disable-floating-tabs-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 12, accepted):

found it on the Document Tab Well advanced options,

[image]

Comment: no worries, came across it whilst trying to find a way to actually disable it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309788/disable-code-window-undock-in-vs2010

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how to turn off it, but you can use  use {CTRL}+ Double click to dock them again

Comment: Great tip. If you have multiple monitors it makes for nice coding and I like this new feature of VS 2010.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that elsewhere, makes this problem a hair less annoying.

Answer (score 1):

As I know [Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) don't change this behaviour. But you should probably add some kind of locking feature on their wish-list.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, because it doesn't appear to be possible.