# Disable code window undock in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, window, docking

I've seen cases where people are asking how to disable on double click.

But i'd like to go one further and disable the feature altogether, does anyone know how to? I don't mean all windows (Properties, Debug, Output) just code windows (Pages, Controls, other files)

I'm using VS2010 SP1 + PowerTools and I keep undocking code windows when selecting the tab if i accidently drag down and it's really frustrating!

Many thanks in advance,
Cheers,
P.

Answer (score 1):

I also don't know any option to disable it, but you can restore the window to its last position by "Ctrl + Double-Click" on the tab's title bar.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

These are two same question:

[Turn off double-click undock in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588214/turn-off-double-click-undock-in-vs2010)

[How to disable floating tabs in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589302/how-to-disable-floating-tabs-in-visual-studio-2010)

For anyone who actually wants the answer to this, in my version of Productivity Power Tools (v10.0.20626.18) there is a way to disable this "feature".

Tools->Options->Productivity Power Tools->Document Tab Well->General->**Advanced Options**...

Under the "Floating Tab Well" group box, uncheck "**Enable float on double-click**"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxODT.png